# mongoimport to remote host always throws connection error

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

So, to start of, I have 2 machines; 1 with the file that is to be imported, and the other hosting a MongoDB instance.

The MongoDB instance is native and running on port 27017. There is no clustering, no SSL enabled. The machine with the file can successfully `telnet HOST 27017` without any issues.

To confirm that there are no problems with the machine with the file connecting to the MongoDB instance, I can successfully run the following:

```
mongosh --host=HOST_IP --port=27017 --username=USERNAME --password="PASSWORD" --authenticationDatabase=admin
```

All that is left is to actually do the import, so I run the following:

```
mongoimport --host=HOST_IP --port=27017 --username=USERNAME --password="PASSWORD" --authenticationDatabase=admin --db=DATABASE --collection=COLLECTION --numInsertionWorkers=3 --type=csv --mode=insert --headerline --file=FILENAME.csv
```

However, at this stage, it fails. This is the result when I run the above with a `-vvvvv` flag:

```
using 4 decoding workers
using 3 insert workers
filesize: 123456 bytes
using fields: A,B,C
will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
[........................] DATABASE.COLLECTION  4.00KB/123KB (0.7%)
[........................] DATABASE.COLLECTION  4.00KB/123KB (3.25%)
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
imported 0 documents
```

How strange. I can `mongosh` in just fine, but the `mongoimport` fails. I changed the connection arguments into a URI just to try it out, but it doesn't help. Curious if the MongoDB instance is even detecting a connection attempt, I check the logs, and I see records which matches the time that come in pairs with the messages `Connection accepted` followed by `Connection ended`.

Since I have access to both devices at this point in time, I transfer the file over and run the same command, but I change the host to `127.0.0.1`, with every other argument remaining the same. And that works without any issues whatsoever.

But I can't do so on said machine moving forward; it needs to be a remote import. But I've hit a wall here, and I have no clue what else to try. Has anybody encountered this issue before, or have any suggestion on what I can try? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: As requested, here is the `mongo.conf` file with the comments removed:

```
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\log\mongod.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

Comment: please provide the mongod.conf file details.

Comment: You might want to try to set the mongod bindip parameter to '0.0.0.0' .  If it is set to 127.0.0.1, only localhost connections are allowed.

Comment: @barrypicker Edited the question to include the configuration file. The bindIp was already set as you mentioned.

Comment: Per your mongoimport command, I will need to try this with a CSV file.  Normally, mongoimport/mongoexport uses JSON...